# Get a print out of INSERTs from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2005 - Export table programatically (run a .sql file to rebuild it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363/sql-server-2005-export-table-programatically-run-a-sql-file-to-rebuild-it)
>   [Generate INSERT statements from a SQL Server Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504884/generate-insert-statements-from-a-sql-server-table)

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 and want to get a printout out of inserts so I can copy and paste them into my production server (I cannot directly link to production server).

I just want a print out of X number of records from a very large table.

```
select * from data where tableID > 10100;
```

The above is the condition I want to use to figure out which records to generate the inserts for.

Comment: Try to gernarate SQL script with data and run it on server. Steps: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the **many** third-party tools around that do this:

1. [SQL Server 2008 R2 - generating INSERT statements for a table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/06/24/sql-server-2008-r2-generating-insert-statements-for-a-table.aspx) (I believe this also works / is also available for the 2005 version)
2. [See this other SO question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table) (and the answers!)
3. [SQL Server 2005 Script to Generate INSERT statements](http://www.keylimetie.com/blog/2009/3/24/sql-server-2005-script-to-generate-insert-statements/)
4. [Generate Insert Statements For a SQL Server Table](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/07/generate-insert-statements-for-sql.html)

or just plain Google (or Bing) for it! There's **tons** of material out there....